# Ao gerar o thumbnail, a imagem vai para o diretório toda preta

Tags: php, thumbnail

O código abaixo é para a criação de thumb. Gostaria de não usar bibliotecas prontas, porém o thumb gerado está indo para a pasta toda preta. O gd2 está ativo no php. Veja:

```
$foto = "imagens/fox.jpg";

$diretorioNormal = "imagens/normal/";
$diretorioThumb = "imagens/thumb/";

// Tamanho do arquivo
$tamanhoMaximo = 1024 * 1024 * 3; // 3Mb
$tamanhoArquivo = filesize($foto);

// Extensao da foto
list($arquivo,$extensao) = explode(".",$foto);

// Dimensões da imagem
list($largura,$altura) = getimagesize($foto);

if($tamanhoArquivo > $tamanhoMaximo){
    $erro = "O arquivo não pode ser superior a 3Mb";
}else if($extensao != 'jpg' && $extensao != 'png'){
    $erro = "A extensão do arquivo tem que ser jpg ou png";
}else{

    // Criando e codificando padronizando para extensão jpg
    $codificarFoto = md5($arquivo.time()).".jpg";   

    // Novas dimensões da imagem
    $novaLargura = 200;
    $novaAltura = 200;

    // Gerar a miniatura
    $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
    $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($codificarFoto);
    imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);

    // Qualidade da imagem
    //copy($codificarFoto, $diretorioThumb.$codificarFoto);
    imagejpeg($miniatura,$diretorioThumb.$codificarFoto,50);

    // destruir a imagem
    imagedestroy($miniatura);
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente o seu script não está encontrando a imagem "fox.jpg", logo é gerada uma imagem preta. Utilize a função "file_exists" para verificar se o sistema encontra a imagem.

Comment: Filipe. A imagem existe, já fiz o teste.

Comment: Qual a largura e altura da imagem "fox.jpg"?

Comment: a dimensão real é 960 X 720...

Comment: Veja se esse tópico ajuda (inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551747/why-does-this-basic-imagejpeg-resizer-returns-a-black-image

Comment: Me dá uma dica de como deveria ser a pergunta... pois coloquei o problema que estou passando no momento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema está na seguinte linha:

```
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($codificarFoto);
```

Veja, a função (imagecreatefromjpeg) é para criar (create) uma imagem (image) a partir de (from) um jpeg.

A variável "$codificarFoto" é apenas uma string que você criou anteriormente para dar nome a nova imagem que será gerada, a imagem ainda não existe no HD e não pode dar origem a uma outra imagem.

Troque a linha pelo seguinte código:

```
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto);
```

Veja, a variável "$foto" representa uma imagem que de fato existe no seu disco, é a partir dela que vai ser gerada uma nova imagem.

Comment: Bingo Filipe... exatamente isso... muito obrigado pela sua ajuda...